# Why does this code not run?

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

```
void myThread(void *arg) {
    printf("Thread ran!\n");
    pthread_exit( NULL );
}

int main() {
    int ret;
    pthread_t mythread;
    ret=pthread_create(&mythread,NULL,myThread,NULL);
    if (ret != 0) {
            printf( "Can’t create pthread (%s)\n", strerror(errno ) );
            exit(-1);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to wait in the main thread, use `pthread_join()` after calling `pthread_create()`.

Answer (score 9):

Because `main` returns immediately, before the thread has had a chance to execute - try adding `sleep(1000);` before `return 0;` and you'll probably find that it works.

If you'd like `main` to wait until the thread finishes, try [pthread_join](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/pthread_join.3.html) (but then you might as well not have a thread at all).

```
pthread_join(mythread, 0);
return 0;
```

Comment: why is sleep() your first advice? It is a bad practice in this case.

Comment: Just to demonstrate, really. It's obvious what sleep does but not so obvious what pthread_join does if you're new to multithreading.

Comment: Thank you,but consider that errors of this code is as follows: 
1)undefined reference to `pthread_create' 
2)make: *** [Test] Error 1

Comment: I am find it.My eclipse could not compile my project with pthread library.

Comment: For set it :right click on project name->properties->c/c++ Build->setting-> GCC C Linker->Libraries and add pthread.Good luck.

Comment: Alternatively you can call `pthread_exit()` in `main()` instead of a normal return.  This will prevent the implicit `exit()` that returning from `main()` performs so the program will continue to run until all threads have exited.  Note that if you're running on Windows using the pthread-win32 port this won't work (exiting the 'main' thread on windows terminates the process).